# Python 2 to 3 conversion for HMAC

Tags: python

I know it may sound like I am jumping the gun asking this. However I have been banging my head against this for hours. I am trying to get a response from `BTC-e` and I have a working python2 version that simply fails in python3. I tried automatedly converting it, looking up package name changes etc. Just dies on me. Here is the working python2 sample: (Not my code)

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import httplib
import urllib
import json
import hashlib
import hmac
from auth import Ekey, Esecret

# Replace these with your own API key data
BTC_api_key = Ekey
BTC_api_secret = Esecret
# Come up with your own method for choosing an incrementing nonce
def generate_nonce(length=8):
"""Generate pseudorandom number."""
return ''.join([str(random.randint(0, 9)) for i in range(length)])

nonce = generate_nonce()

# method name and nonce go into the POST parameters
params = {"method":"getInfo",
          "nonce": nonce}
params = urllib.urlencode(params)

# Hash the params string to produce the Sign header value
H = hmac.new(BTC_api_secret, digestmod=hashlib.sha512)
H.update(params)
sign = H.hexdigest()

headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                   "Key":BTC_api_key,
                   "Sign":sign}
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("btc-e.com")
conn.request("POST", "/tapi", params, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()

print response.status, response.reason
print json.load(response)

conn.close()
```

Then the unfortunate stack overflow concoction I scalped from somewhere which returns invalid signature.

```
 #! /usr/bin/python3
from time import time
import urllib.parse
import hashlib
import hmac
import requests
import json
APIKey = b'key-key-key'
secret = b'secret'
url = "https://btc-e.com/tapi"

payload = {
    'method': 'getInfo',
    'nonce': int(time() * 1000),
}

paybytes = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload).encode()
print(paybytes)

sign = hmac.new(secret, paybytes, digestmod=hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
print(sign)

headers = {
    "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'Key':APIKey,
    'Sign': sign
}
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=paybytes)
result = r.json()
print(result)
```

How/why are they different? For api docs I am trying to use this with [go here](https://btc-e.com/).

Comment: You're probably getting down-voted because you haven't provided a [mcve], which is critical to our ability to debug your code. Please update your question to include one—"why isn't my code working" requires a **clear problem statement**. You may want to look at [ask].

Comment: @JasonBasanese: Your question's not bad, I don't see why it's being downvoted. It's a little hard to provide a working example if it requires private API keys.

Comment: I'll probably edit it to make more sense tommorow.

Comment: // , Please edit... should be a question...? Looks like you posted this at 01:00 AM your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your nonce is too big. From the [API docs](https://btc-e.com/tapi/docs#auth) of that website you linked to:

> Minimum nonce value - `1`, maximum - `4294967294`.

The current timestamp is 1495778924773, which is much bigger than 4294967294.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that now.

Comment: That was it... It's always the little things.